# How to generate the "Generated Code" from the zoho console "Self Client" using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, crm, zoho

How to generate that 'generated code' from that 'self client'? I can easily do it from Zoho console, But how to do it from Node.js? Thanks for your help.

I am trying to generate the "Generated Code" from "Self Client" using Node.js. How can I do that?

[Generated code from self client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FwYN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SDKs (in any programming language) for generating the code. SDKs can only be used for generating Access and Refresh tokens.

You can have to generate it by making [a request](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/web-apps/authorization.html) in web browser and sign in into your account.

For generating the code other than Self Client, you can refer this docs: [Setup OAuth with Zoho](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth-setup.html)